Issue with Mongo Typescript InferId
I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here. Mongo defines InferTypeId as follows:
export declare type InferIdType<TSchema> = TSchema extends {
    _id: infer IdType;
} ? Record<any, never> extends IdType ? never : IdType : TSchema extends {
    _id?: infer IdType;
} ? unknown extends IdType ? ObjectId : IdType : ObjectId;

For the purposes of this example, it can be simplified such that every branch of the inference returns string.
I have a class that takes in a schema where the _id is expected to be a string (For sanity I also tried with ObjectId and literal values).
class X<T extends { _id: string }> {
    constructor() {
    const x: InferIdType<T> = "test";
    }
}

This causes an error on the assignment to x, saying Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'InferIdType<T>'.
You can see a simple reproduction here
My question is: Why is InferIdType unable to infer the ID type of a generic that specifies the _id format?
